# mPDF error on Codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter, pdf, controller, mpdf

I tried to convert a html page to pdf and was decided to use mPDF, I follow what the documentation does. When running the code, it does not prompt out the PDF to ask for save. Btw I get those error code.

Here is the code from Controller.

```
    //this data will be passed on to the view
    $data['the_content']='mPDF and CodeIgniter are cool!';

    //load the view, pass the variable and do not show it but "save" the output into $html variable
    $html=$this->load->view('ajax/pdf_output', $data, true); 

    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "the_pdf_output.pdf";

    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //actually, you can pass mPDF parameter on this load() function
    $pdf = $this->m_pdf->load();
    //generate the PDF!
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //offer it to user via browser download! (The PDF won't be saved on your server HDD)
    $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");
```

Below is the result i get:
%PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x��P]O�@���㓚����^�1�h�7�C��B(h���sW�Fs����vvv�B')�ձCgha�6��Mp�6�    �H�U[P��{��-[�uz��#��뮉�r�@Υ�9�R���'�J�h&���e� �J�YW�f����\���/�m�Ӷ�����J.w���j��N�ގ��^�=f!��ƲO����o�92yh�`m���9�  �e��[��#�3���?u�R%_�¿�)�X|jt2H׆��+��S��`™9%�R��:��ƒ7��m��Z����9n� endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj 7 0 obj <> endobj 8 0 obj <> stream /CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin 12 dict begin begincmap /CIDSystemInfo <> def /CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def /CMapType 2 def 1 begincodespacerange <0000> endcodespacerange 1 beginbfrange <0000> <0000> endbfrange endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop end end endstream endobj 9 0 obj <> endobj 10 0 obj < >> /FontFile2 12 0 R >> endobj 11 0 obj <> stream x����V�����Qfd%{dT*�l-�Ȉ��_����s��ڥ����}��@;���t���:��Nt�S�n�3�m�s��B��h��JW���nt�[��Nw�^�{��&�l�GM7�l�{���z��^4��^��7��]���B�-��J���V[�K�}�[}�G?��f���V���n���w�� endstream endobj 12 0 obj <> stream x��| \TU��9��;�.�zqIe�]ce�t`��apfQQ�q�qGKSS+5-K+Ӟ�z�6�35���gi���wν3d=��}����g�s�=������\0�B��4#+76�r����=\��}�O��:�p <7�r���G~BHH���EŖ�j��B�C_U��W /� q<��U�}��<�!��t�Qo��ۀPdwXN���<���X���<�~]��Po3oC(��_��gW��Ўz��r��8�XR!<����+�vG�B4�Q��� ����Z�<���(��^�Dhk��@��r'WQ����h4�F��i�Fw���H$�]�3�$77kBi(��e��A�=7�"凨����C���]D��.=�onf�577���l��$��y#����? ��CA(�G!(���#��:�Ѓ��uE݀�p�"Qw�z�����F}P4��bP,����8�EP<���h����h�yQJF)H�R�(4��1h,JG(e�l4��\��ƣ|4MD�@�S�T4 =���H:�Ev$���-�|�tdF3�r��w�\�����>�����~�N��0O`Z�ˀ���;0����>�H����m� $Z�|�^t�E��r�Uo�l/�ì-���a^� �$@�΢O�b�*A5h ��L�]��tx1�� ��$d�Y�Y�� Jf��,��W�qo�Cf�"<$�a2z�"�8>=�'�˧� s��*/z[�*�{��@��x���op:.��O�A{�?p�Yz����������-ޡ��!y��  }kP&� T�]��H"0���� Qi�c    �&�oL ���Q�c���������Ҥc�C�H��11*�� ��=6{�|��.EE��H��܉�dO� �����[ ,~O�5�֓*��І,>�lozG��s�� ���6Mo��^�m���� 0P�!,T�#DK�"�����SS�ku��#�%�33�̐�hz��I�z�v�zNG��`���N���"�a�[

Anyone can tell me what happening with this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the "I" parameter is causing trouble because the browser doesn't recognize your file

according to the [docu](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/output.html) you've the following Possibilities:

I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if available. The name given by $filename is used when one selects the “Save as” option on the link generating the PDF.

D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given by $filename.

F: save to a local file with the name given by $filename (may include a path).

S: return the document as a string. $filename is ignored.

try something like that :

```
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
die;
```

or on the other hand you can try to add some header to tell the browser explicitly this is a pdf document

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf'); 
$pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");
die;
```

because it could be CIs outpout class overwrites MPDF's header (but this is just a hunch)

Comment: I was tried for both, either "I" or "D". it return same error.

Comment: is it something block it or?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $html=$this->load->view("ajax/pdf_output",$data,true);
    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');
    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    //download it.
    ob_clean(); 
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,'F');

 check your folder.....
```

Comment: Hi Kuldeep, $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,'F'); are working fine.. but it's auto saved into server. Any idea on prompt out and ask for save?

Answer (score 0):

If you want show download dialogue your need to place below code

```
$filename = time()."_order.pdf"; //your file name 
$html = $this->load->view('unpaid_voucher2',$data,true);
 /// $data variable is your dynamic data if you have no dynmic data then you can pass empty instead of variable like.
$html = $this->load->view('unpaid_voucher2','',true);
$this->load->library('M_pdf');
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

 //For download pass D and save on server pass F.
 $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output("./uploads/".$filename, "D");
```

Here is full configuration to [integrate mpdf into codeigniter](https://github.com/phpclicks/mpdf)

Answer (score 0):

The string is a binary PDF representation and its presence means `Content-type: application/pdf` header is not sent correctly or it is
overriden by your code or setup. Most likely by `text/plain` or `text/html`.

Try to figure out these:

- Are you resetting `Content-type` header in PHP code somewhere after calling the mPDF `Output` method?
- Is your server forcing a different `Content-type` somewhere in your setup?
- Does your browser support displaying `application/pdf` Content-type directly?

Given that the `D` Output mode gives you the same result, I'd guess the `Content-type` header is being overriden somewhere after calling the `Output` method, presumably by CodeIgniter.